# ¿Como obtengo una zona horaria en especifica? Jquery

Tags: jquery

Titulo, quisiera hacer una variable en jquery que hace llamar esta zona horaria: 'America/Mazatlan', pero no tengo idea cual es el metodo y si ocupo alguna libreria ademas para serlo funcionar, denme detalles!

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, he dado una respuesta sólo porque la otra respuesta que has aceptado como válida tiene un error. Te sugiero leer [ask] y [mcve]. Entiendo que no sabes cómo atacar el problema, pero para eso está la documentación, debes leer la misma e intentar primero antes de publicar una pregunta tan abierta. Espero lo tomes en cuenta para la próxima vez que necesites ayuda. Siempre estaremos dispuestos a ayudarte, pero debes mostrar lo que hayas intentado. Por otro lado, disculpa que te diga esto, pero *ocupar* no es sinónimo de *usar* ni de *necesitar*. Saludos

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo no sabia como se llamaba la zona horaria de esa region en especifica, por lo que investigue y esta coordinada con:

[America/Mazatlan](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/es/timezone/america--mazatlan)

Ahora ya sabiendo que es `NA`, entonces procedamos a la respuesta de la pregunta:

```js
const americaMazatlanDate = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {hour12: false});
console.log(americaMazatlanDate);
```

con localeString segun la documentacion de mozilla puedes especificarle que zona horaria usar, pasandole como parametro la zona horaria:

[Date.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toLocaleString)

Aunque si esto no es lo que deseas o es incorrecta la zona horaria, entonces puedes cambiarle los parametros para ajustar la zona horaria.

Por si caso si te interesa tambien esta `UTC` que es la hora universal coordinada:

```js
const americaMazatlanDate = new Date().toUTCString();
console.log(americaMazatlanDate);
```

La verdad es que no se como serian los parametros para esa region en especifico, incluso no se si este soportada, pero lo mas cercano es usar `es-MX` o `en-US`, segun veo, si vives en esa region deberás comprobar cual de las dos se acerca mas.

Comment: Nota: la compatibilidad en interpretes de codigo difiere, aqui en stackoverflow a no todos por igual le apareceran cambios en la zona horaria al modificar el codigo en el snippet y ejecutarlo desde aqui, por lo que si ejecutas el codigo directamente desde tu maquina en un archivo o si la corres en un servidor funcionara sin problemas,  llegue a notar esto hace unas semanas, cuando la zona horaria no queria darme cambios, por lo que lo intente en local o en un servidor y la zona horaria funcionaba de manera correcta.

Comment: eres grande drake, bien explicado.

Comment: La zona horaria en mi ordenador es GMT+02:00 (Europa / Hora de verano), y tu método no me da la hora de *Mazatlán*, me da la hora de España. Revisa tu respuesta.

Comment: No creo que esta sea una pregunta muy amplia,  he visto mucha gente que pregunta estas cosas y no entiendo porque son cerradas,  si javascript ya provee estas superfunciones que te acortan mucho el problema,  es decir,  mi respuesta como ves no conlleva muchas lineas,  pero en la otra parte si te doy la razon,  la zona horaria es incorrecta,  pero esto es lo que he explicado en mi pregunta,  realmente no sabia como establecer bien esa zona horaria de esa region en especifico,  pense que solo se podia por codigos de pais y lenguaje.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la fecha y hora en la zona horaria específica de una región puedes usar el método [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/toLocaleString).

El mismo recibe 2 [parámetros](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#Parameters) opcionales:

- `locales`: Un tipo `String` con formato [BCP 47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) de la [IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).
- `options`: Un objeto con diferentes opciones, entre las cuales se encuentra `timeZone`. Este campo o tributo indica la zona horaria a usar. su valor predeterminado es la zona horaria del cliente, pero se pueden establecer valores que sean compatibles con la lista de zonas horarias de la base de datos de la [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

La zona horaria que aplica para la ciudad de [Mazatlán](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazatl%C3%A1n), según la base de datos de la IANA, es: `America/Mazatlan`.

Una forma de ver esto en acción sería construir una función que reciba una zona horaria con el formato IANA correcto y construir un objeto de tipo `Date` para luego devolver el valor del método `toLocaleString()` con los parámetros adecuados.

Por ejemplo, vamos a escribir una función que reciba un argumento para el valor de `locale` y un argumento para el valor de `options`:

```js
const getTZDate = (locale, timeZone) => {
  const date = new Date();
  return date.toLocaleString(locale, {timeZone: timeZone});
}

const localeMX = 'es-MX';
const localeVE = 'es-VE';
const localeDefault = 'es-ES';
const caracas = 'America/Caracas';
const mazatlan = 'America/Mazatlan';
const fecha1 = getTZDate(localeMX, mazatlan);
const fecha2 = getTZDate(localeVE, caracas);
const fecha3 = getTZDate(localeDefault);

console.log(`Hora y fecha actual en Mazatlán - México: ${fecha1}`);
console.log(`Hora y fecha actual en Caracas - Venezuela: ${fecha2}`);
console.log(`Hora y fecha actual por defecto: ${fecha3}`);
```

Puedes notar que la salida no solo indica la fecha local de cada zona horaria, sino que el valor `locale` influye en la forma en que el método `toLocaleString()` de formato a la salida. Para el caso de Caracas, uso la cadena `es-VE`, lo cual agrega un valor `a.m.` o `p.m.` según la hora calculada.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.